# Fundamental Data Types Program

Tags: c++, pointers, types, primitive-types

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    char c;
    int i;
    short int j;
    long int k;
    float f;
    double d;
    long double e;

    cout << "The size of char is: " << sizeof c << endl;
    cout << "The size of int is: " << sizeof i << endl;
    cout << "The size of short int is: " << sizeof j << endl;
    cout << "The size of long int is: " << sizeof k << endl;
    cout << "The size of float is: " << sizeof f << endl;
    cout << "The size of double is: " << sizeof d << endl;
    cout << "The size of long double is: " << sizeof e << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The purpose of this program is to print out the size of the fundamental data types, which I think I have accomplished.  The other purpose of this program is to print the size of the pointer to each of these data types.  I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do this.  I understand that a pointer is a variable which stores the address of another variable and that pointers involve the deference operator (*).  Can anyone please provide a suggestion?  I'm not looking for the answer, just a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. `sizeof(&k)`? By the way I think you will find the answer to this is somewhat boring ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
int *p; // p is a pointer to an int
```

So sizeof the pointer would be: `sizeof p`, which you could print as:

```
cout << "The size of int pointer is: " << sizeof p << endl;
```

This is what you need to do print other pointers' sizes.

*Dereferencing* is only done when you want to access what a pointer is pointing to.
E.g.

```
int i = 5;
int *p = &i;

*p = 6;
*p = *p + 1; 
//etc
```

Here, you just want to get the size of the pointers. So no dereferencing is needed.

Comment: So, for example, can I just do:

char *c; // c is a pointer to a char

cout << "The size of char is: " << sizeof c << endl;
cout << "The size of char pointer is: " << sizeof c << endl;

Thank you for your help.

Comment: @user3727648 The size of the character would be `sizeof *c` while the size of the pointer would be `sizeof c`.